# Apply class method to an object in another class in Python 2.7

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a code in Python 2.7 that represents a LineString and then move the LineString by the defined x, y values (in this case (-1, -1)). 
I'm using two classes.

First is class Points that represents the single x, y of each line and second is class LineString where I'm first converting the tuple of x,y line points (p) to a list using the Point class.

What I'm stick with is how to apply the move function in class Points to LineString move.

In other words by using Points internally in the LineString class I should be able to use the move() implemented in the Point class instead of implementing it again in the Line String class.

I went through similar forums but could not find answer to my problem. So, I will be thankful for any advice.

```
from itertools import starmap

class Point(object):

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def move(self, move_x, move_y):
        self.x = self.x + move_x
        self.y += move_y

class LineString(object):

    def __init__(self, *args): 
        print 'These are the arguments as tuple of tuples:', args 
        self.points = [Point(*p) for p in args]


    def move(self, move_x, move_y):
        for p in self.points:
            p.move() # This is the part I don't know how to implement 
                          # the move method for each point p


    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.points[index]


if __name__ == '__main__':

    lin1 = LineString((1, 1), (0, 2))

    lin1.move(-1, -1) # Move by -1 and -1 for x and y respectively

    assert lin1[0].y == 0 # Inspect the y value of the start point.


    lin2 = LineString((1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 2))

    lin2.move(-1, -1) # Move by -1 and -1 for x and y respectively

    assert lin2[-1].x == 1 # Inspect the x value of the end point.


    print 'Success! Line tests passed!'
```

Comment: `Point.move()` expects two params.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're overthinking this. Whatever arguments you pass to `LineString.move` have to be passed on to `Point.move` as well.

```
def move(self, move_x, move_y):
    for p in self.points:
        p.move(move_x, move_y)
```